# mutual information in kmeans clustering R package

Tags: r, distance, correlation, k-means

Is there a package in R that we can use/specify Mutual Information in kmeans clustering? 
Or how can I use this metric in kmeans?

Thank you in advance!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#Metric

http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-26981-9_11

Comment: I think you would get more views and a better chance of an answer if you expanded your question a bit. Perhaps link to some site that explains "mutual information"?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I was referring to MI as a measure of distance between variables. http://conferences.telecom-bretagne.eu/asmda2005/IMG/pdf/proceedings/738.pdf

Comment: I'd be interested on the reply to this question too. Not sure if comment here bring the question up on the list but I upvoted it.